# Extremely laggy touchpad after drop EDIT : After plugging to power source

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, touchpad, laptop-repair

LOOK at EDIT 4 at first!

I dropped my laptop - Acer Aspire 5742z and everything works fine but the touchpad.

It looks like touchpad send the information about position of finger every 500 ms or even more rarely.

Do you have any idea what could be a reason for such a behaviour ? I would understand touchpad not working (because say, connectors are broken afer drop) but "lagging touchpad" ?

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: It is not software issue - I check it on two operating systems (Windows 8 and Debian Linux)

EDIT:

What is even more strange, the lag doesn't have stable "interval", in the 2 hours of using such an touchpad, there are times when lag is 500 ms, and there are times when lags almost disappear.

EDIT2:

After 5/6 hours, the touchpad comes to live without lagging. Miracle.  Is there anybody who could explain this ? I'm dubious but maybe somebody encounter the same problem ?

EDIT3:

I was actually experienced the problem only in one place! In my library when I plug my laptop to the power!

Amazingly, when I unplugged my laptop it works perfectly, when you plug it again (to this outlet) it makes my touchpad laggy again!

EDIT4:
I posted on the Library's Facebook page, and I got response that this is common problem.
Even very common problem. And they don't know why this happened.

Comment: Marginal connection, i.e. partly broken solder joint? Position or heat expansion could be working in your favor.